# How to synchronize 3 observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, operators

I have 3 observables a, b and c that I call on page load to get the needed data.  b is dependent on a.  c is independent.

I want to know when I have fetched data from all of them so I can set the is loading to false.  Also what would be best practice in terms of catching errors and syncing these observables?

Comment: there is not here to help you - you should post the service or component that you are trying to accomplish this on.

Comment: We'd love to help, but to provide a useful response we need to know a little more about what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide some code (or at least some pseudo code) or better yet build a stackblitz that demonstrates your specific scenario? Here is one possibility: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-posts-with-three-chains

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote "`a` depends on `b`" then I can assume that `b` is something like `a.pipe(...)` and apparently if `b` has received a value then `a` has recieved it too.

Then we need to know when both `b` and `c` recieved a value to set `loading` to false.
For this purpose you can use `combineLatest` operator. For details and requested best practices please take a look at this great article:
https://indepth.dev/posts/1114/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams#combinelatest

Answer (score 0):

The `zip` function is perfect for this case. It emits only when all the observables passed to it emit

basically:

```
zip(a,b,c).subscribe(_ => this.loading = false); 

// potentially also zip(b,c) since a is dependant on b but since 
// no code was provided , its hard to tell
```

you can pipe a catchError() to it in case of errors

ref: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip#after-all-observables-emit-emit-values-as-an-array)